# Split string and get last element

Tags: regex, google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, re2

Let's say I have a column which has values like:

```
foo/bar
chunky/bacon/flavor
/baz/quz/qux/bax
```

I.e. a variable number of strings separated by `/`.

In another column I want to get the last element from each of these strings, after they have been split on `/`.  So, that column would have:

```
bar
flavor
bax
```

I can't figure this out.  I can split on `/` and get an array, and I can see the function INDEX to get a specific numbered indexed element from the array, but can't find a way to say "the last element" in this function.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

**Edit:**
this one is simplier:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"[^/]+$")
```

---

You could use this formula:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(?:.*/)(.*)$")
```

And also possible to use it as ArrayFormula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A3,"(?:.*/)(.*)$"))
```

Here's some more info:

- the [RegExExtract function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en)
- [Some good examples of syntax](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YFyOFSm7P4pssBMY7qTrWinz2SDMZW1KUnkmePDORS0/preview)
- my personal [list of Regex Tricks](https://sheetswithmaxmakhrov.wordpress.com/2019/09/20/google-sheets-and-regular-expressions/)

---

This formula will do the same:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(A1,"/"),LEN(A1)-len(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","")))
```

But it takes A1 three times, which is not prefferable.

Answer (score 5):

You could do this too

```
=index(SPLIT(A1, "/"), COLUMNS(SPLIT(A1, "/"))-1)
```

Comment: What are the benefits or tradeoffs of this approach compared to the options outlined in the accepted answer?

Comment: The advantage is that it does not require an understanding of regex. I like regex, but i didn't always

Answer (score 2):

Also possible, perhaps best on a copy, with Find:

```
.+/
```

(`Replace with` blank) and `Search using regular expressions` ticked.

Answer (score -6):

You can try use this!

You've got the array of String, so you can acess the last element by length

```
String message =  "chunky/bacon/flavor";
String[] outSplited = message.split("/");

System.out.println(outSplited[outSplited.length -1]);
```

Comment: Guessing the downvotes are because this is in Java and the question is about using google sheets