# Google Spreadsheet: Split String and return last N elements

Tags: google-sheets

I have string ( "-" ) delimited data (alphanumeric, variable length) in a single column which has the format...

```
Column A
"aaa-bbb-ccc"
"ddd-bbb-eee"
"aaa-fff-ggg"
```

I have been able to use [array_constrain()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267036?visit_id=1-636241489150159480-3111130743&hl=en-GB&rd=1) to return partial data elsewhere but this is N elements from the beginning of the array to the end of the array so I could have...

```
aaa               (num_cols = 1)
aaa-bbb           (num_cols = 2)
aaa-bbb-ccc       (num_cols = 3)
```

I am looking to get the last N elements from the split data so...

```
bbb-ccc   OR 
ccc
```

num_cols only goes from the beginning of the array to the back of the array so that's no good for my scenario.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37390263) to a similar question suggests using [regexextract()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en) to retrieve the last value which if my RegEx Foo was stronger then perhaps I could make that work with a little nudge in the right direction.

I know that [index()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en) can be used but that only returns one element at a time from the split data so that gets messy / inefficient.

So the question is does anybody know how to return the last N elements from an array? Ordinary sorting wouldn't work but reversing the array could work.

Comment: I don't know if this will work in google sheets or if I understand what you're trying to do but `=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT("-",100)),100))` gets the last bit of text, `=TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," -,REPT("-",40)),60),40))` gets the second last and if you increase the 60 by 80 to 120 you'll get the 3rd last, 200 the forth last etc.  i don't know if that helps at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `reverse` function. I see two ways:

1. write small function is sctipt: reverse array
2. use ugly huge formula

**Huge formula sample**

`=JOIN("-",QUERY({ArrayFormula(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(SPLIT(A1,"-"))))),TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1,"-"))},"select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 2 "))`

change `limit 2` in the end of the formula to get N last elements.

---

**Script sample**

Try this:

```
function reverseLine(line) {
  return line[0].reverse();
}
```

Use as custom formula: `=reverseLine(B1:D1)`
for line: `aaa  bbb ccc` returns:

```
ccc
bbb
aaa
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided the variable length is exclusively from the number of sets of the format `-aaa` appended to the first three characters then those three characters and as many further sets as desired may be stripped off the front with:

```
=replace(A1,1,find("-",A1)*B1,"")
```

where A1 contains the likes of `aaa-bbb-ccc` and B1 the number of sets additional to the first three characters to be removed, plus one.