# How to extract a string seperated in brackets at the end of a cell, if two or more bracketed strings are present

Tags: regex, google-sheets, split

I need to sperate strings in a Google spreadsheet. The extraction target is a string in [] brackets at the end of the cell. A string in [] brackets at the beginning or in the middle of the cell has to be ignored. Is there a possibility to target the cells from the right side?

The extraction with RegexExtract like

```
=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"\[(.*?)\]");"")
```

works only for cells with one bracket and copies the content of the brackets, I want to split it off.

Otherwise for example

```
=SPLIT(CHANGE(A1;"[";"^");"^")
```

does not ignore the irrelvant brackets.

#### Example

Original Cell Content:

> [irrelevant] Lore [irrelevant] Ipsum 123 [relevant String]

I want to have one cell with:

> [irrelevant] Lore [irrelevant] Ipsum 123

And another cell with:

> [relevant String]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for the second cell:

`=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"[(.*?)]$");"")`

For the first cell:

`=LEFT(A1, LEN(A1) - LEN(<second cell reference>))`

Source:
[Google spreadsheet: split string and get last element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37390009/google-spreadsheet-split-string-and-get-last-element)

**UPD:**

Also there is a hack to get last occurence of something if you can get only the first occurence:

1. Reverse the string
2. Find the first occurence in the reversed string

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but also try

```
=regexextract(A1, "(.+?)(\[[^\[]+$)")
```